# How to group UITableView with section mentioned in JSON value

Tags: ios, uitableview

I get [this json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CgY6itgnBMFwkUe7iNu8o9qGJHcFjJP6VFG3isb5jwE) from web service and I need to group it depending on "PRICELISTCATEGORY" value. I tried the following code, but I get repeated rows and sections in the table. I collect the web service array in `self.arrayPriceList`. What am I doing wrong?

After collecting the array from json web service, I call `[self didReceiveResponseJson:self.arrayPriceList];`

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)priceListCategoryDitionaryAllReadyExist:(NSString *)price {

    for(NSMutableDictionary *priceListDict in self.arrayPriceList){
        if([[[priceListDict objectForKey:@"PRICELISTCATEGORY"] objectForKey:@"text"] isEqualToString:price])
            //return the existing array refrence to add
            return priceListDict;
    }
    // if we dont found then we will come here and return nil
    return nil;
}

-(void)didReceiveResponseJson:(NSMutableArray *)jsonArray {

    for(NSDictionary *priceDict in jsonArray) {

        NSMutableDictionary *existingPriceListDict=[self priceListCategoryDitionaryAllReadyExist:[[priceDict objectForKey:@"PRICELISTCATEGORY"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
        NSMutableArray *existingTempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        if(existingPriceListDict != nil) {
            //if name exist add in existing array....
            [existingTempArray addObject:priceDict];
        }
        else {
            // create new price list array
            NSMutableArray *newPriceListArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            // Add name dictionary in it
            [newPriceListArray addObject:priceDict];

            // add this newly created pricelist array in globalNameArray
            [self.arrayPriceList addObject:newPriceListArray];
        }
    }

    //so at the end print global array you will get dynamic array with the there respetive dict.
    //NSLog(@"Table array %@", self.arrayPriceList);
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TGAPriceListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TGAPriceListCellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *dict;
    if (self.isFiltered) {
        dict = [self.arrayFilteredPriceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        dict = [self.arrayPriceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }
    cell.lblAPNBarCode.text = [[dict objectForKey:@"APNBARCODE"] objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.lblAvgCost.text = [[dict objectForKey:@"AVERAGECOST"] objectForKey:@"text"];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.isFiltered) {
        return self.arrayFilteredPriceList.count;
    } else {
        NSArray *arrayPrice = [self.arrayPriceList objectAtIndex:section];
        return [arrayPrice count];
    }

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.arrayPriceList count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSDictionary *arrayPrice = [self.arrayPriceList objectAtIndex:section];
    if([arrayPrice count]) {
        return [[arrayPrice objectForKey:@"PRICELISTCATEGORY"] objectForKey:@"text"];
    }
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Comment: From where your are calling tableView.reload function?

Comment: in viewDidLoad after getting the json response.

Comment: @SMi Please refer my edit.

Answer (score 0):

After calling didReceiveResponseJson in viewDidLoad

```
self.arrayPriceList = [NSMutableArray array];
self.dictPriceList = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

I made changes in tableview datasource methods

```
    -(void)didReceiveResponseJson:(NSMutableArray *)jsonArray {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonArray ) {
            NSString *strPriceListCategory = [[dict objectForKey:@"PRICELISTCATEGORY"] objectForKey:@"text"];
            if ([[self.dictPriceList allKeys] containsObject:strPriceListCategory]) {
                NSMutableArray *arrayTemp = [self.dictPriceList objectForKey:strPriceListCategory];
                [arrayTemp addObject:dict];
                [self.dictPriceList setObject:arrayTemp forKey:strPriceListCategory];
            } else {
                NSMutableArray *arrayTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict, nil];
                [self.dictPriceList setObject:arrayTemp forKey:strPriceListCategory];
            }
        }
    }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TGAPriceListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TGAPriceListCellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *dict;
    if (self.isFiltered) {
        dict = [self.arrayFilteredPriceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        NSArray *arrayPriceListAllKeys = [self.dictPriceList allKeys];
        NSArray *arrayPrice = [self.dictPriceList objectForKey:[arrayPriceListAllKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        dict = [arrayPrice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.lblAPNBarCode.text = [[dict objectForKey:@"APNBARCODE"] objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.lblAvgCost.text = [[dict objectForKey:@"AVERAGECOST"] objectForKey:@"text"];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.isFiltered) {
        return self.arrayFilteredPriceList.count;
    } else {
        NSArray *arrayPriceListAllKeys = [self.dictPriceList allKeys];
        NSArray *arrayPrice = [self.dictPriceList objectForKey:[arrayPriceListAllKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
        return [arrayPrice count];
    }

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.dictPriceList allKeys] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *price = [[self.dictPriceList allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
    return price;
}
```